# How to get the Total Pay per trip for each Carrier using a SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016, ssms-2016

I am trying to get this SQL view to total the carrier's pay. I add the Select statement right about the FROM on the top select and the union select, but what it is doing is totaling ALL carriers pay and displaying that amount on every row in the grid return. The field that gets stamped with the pay amount for each additional pay item is pyd_amount. I can get it to work if I add a where clause in the select, but it is taking 37 seconds to open, and the grid has a time out at 30.
Here is the SQL view in question:

```
USE [Database]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[OperationsTripViewDetails_Venture_NOPAY]    Script Date: 2/1/2019 11:32:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO






--71330,66418 
ALTER view [dbo].[OperationsTripViewDetails_Venture_NOPAY]
as     

select a.OrderNumber, 
    a.DispStatus, a.OrderHeaderNumber, a.ord_shipper, a.ord_consignee,  
    a.StartDate, ISNULL(fc.cmp_id, '') as OriginId, ISNULL(fc.cmp_name, '') as OriginName, fcy.cty_nmstct as OriginCity, fcy.cty_state as OriginState, fcy.cty_zip as OriginZip,     
    a.EndDate, ISNULL(lc.cmp_id, '') as FinalId, ISNULL(lc.cmp_name, '') as FinalName, lcy.cty_nmstct as FinalCity, lcy.cty_state as FinalState, lcy.cty_zip As FinalZip,   
    (select sum(stp_lgh_mileage) from stops (nolock) where stops.lgh_number = a.lgh_number) as Mileage, a.Weight, a.Revenue,     
    a.StopCount, a.Driver1, a.Driver1Name, a.Tractor, a.Trailer1,     
    a.Carrier, a.Driver2, a.Driver2Name, a.Trailer2, a.TrailerType,     
    a.CmdCode, a.CmdDescription, a.CmdCount,    
    a.RevType1, a.RevType1Name, a.RevType2, a.RevType2Name, a.RevType3, a.RevType3Name, a.RevType4, a.RevType4Name,
    a.BookingTerminal, a.ExecutingTerminal, a.RouteId,     
    a.lgh_number, a.TotalMailStatus, a.TotalMailStatusName, a.InStatus,     
    a.BookedBy, a.BillTo, a.OrderBy, a.RefNum,     
    pc.cmp_id as PickupId, pc.cmp_name as PickupName, pc.cty_nmstct as PickupCity, pc.cmp_state as PickupState, pc.cmp_zip as PickupZip, pc.cmp_region1 as PickupRegion1, 
    pc.cmp_region2 as PickupRegion2, pc.cmp_region3 as PickupRegion3, pc.cmp_region4 as PickupRegion4,
    a.Leg_Start, a.Leg_End, a.Leg_StartRegion1, a.Leg_StartRegion2, a.Leg_StartRegion3, a.Leg_StartRegion4,
    a.Leg_EndRegion1,  a.Leg_EndRegion2, a.Leg_EndRegion3, a.Leg_EndRegion4, 
    cc.cmp_id as ConsigneeId, cc.cmp_name as ConsigneeName, cc.cty_nmstct as ConsigneeCity, cc.cmp_zip as ConsigneeZip, cc.cmp_state as ConsigneeState, cc.cmp_region1 as ConsigneeRegion1, 
    cc.cmp_region2 as ConsigneeRegion2, cc.cmp_region3 as ConsigneeRegion3, cc.cmp_region4 as ConsigneeRegion4,

    a.LghType1, 
    (select top 1 [name] from labelfile (nolock) where labeldefinition = 'LghType1' and abbr = a.LghType1) as LghType1Name, 
    a.LghType2, (select top 1 [name] from labelfile (nolock) where labeldefinition = 'LghType2' and abbr = a.lghtype2) as LghType2Name,
    a.TeamLeader, (select top 1 [name] from labelfile(nolock) where labeldefinition = 'TeamLeader' and abbr = a.TeamLeader) As TeamLeaderName,     
    a.OrderStatus, (select top 1 [name] from labelfile (nolock) where labeldefinition = 'DispStatus' and abbr = a.OrderStatus) as OrderStatusName, 
    a.mov_number, a.EtaStatus, a.EtaComment, a.[Priority],
     a.lgh_comment,
     a.lgh_trc_comment,
     a.Remarks,
     a.GPSDate,
     a.GPSLocation,
     a.Pay_Total,
    (select dbo.GetMinutesAway(a.mov_number)) As MinutesAway
from    (
            select rtrim(oh.ord_number)+ case when isnull(legheader.lgh_split_flag,'N') = 'N' then '' else '-' + legheader.lgh_split_flag end as OrderNumber, 
                la.lgh_outstatus as DispStatus, oh.ord_hdrnumber As OrderHeaderNumber,   
                la.lgh_startdate as StartDate, 
                la.lgh_enddate as EndDate, 
                la.lgh_startcty_nmstct as Leg_Start,
                la.lgh_endcty_nmstct as Leg_End,
                la.lgh_startregion1 as Leg_StartRegion1, la.lgh_startregion2 as Leg_StartRegion2, la.lgh_startregion3 as Leg_StartRegion3, la.lgh_startregion4 as Leg_StartRegion4,
                la.lgh_endregion1 as Leg_EndRegion1, la.lgh_endregion2 as Leg_EndRegion2, la.lgh_endregion3 as Leg_EndRegion3, la.lgh_endregion4 as Leg_EndRegion4,
                la.ord_totalweight as Weight, FORMAT (oh.ord_totalcharge,'C','en-us') as Revenue,     
                la.ord_stopcount StopCount, la.lgh_driver1 as Driver1, la.evt_driver1_name Driver1Name, la.lgh_tractor as Tractor, la.lgh_primary_trailer as Trailer1,     
                la.lgh_carrier as Carrier, la.lgh_driver2 as Driver2, la.evt_driver2_name Driver2Name, la.lgh_primary_pup as Trailer2, oh.trl_type1 TrailerType,     
                la.cmd_code as CmdCode, la.fgt_description as CmdDescription, la.cmd_count as CmdCount,    
                la.lgh_class1 as RevType1, la.lgh_class1_name as RevType1Name, la.lgh_class2 as RevType2, la.lgh_class2_name as RevType2Name, la.lgh_class3 as RevType3, la.lgh_class3_name as RevType3Name, la.lgh_class4 as RevType4, la.lgh_class4_name as RevType4Name,
                ord_booked_revtype1 as BookingTerminal, la.lgh_booked_revtype1 as ExecutingTerminal, la.lgh_route RouteId,     
                la.lgh_number, la.lgh_tm_status as TotalMailStatus, la.lgh_tm_statusname as TotalMailStatusName, la.lgh_instatus as InStatus,     
                oh.ord_bookedby as BookedBy, oh.ord_billto as BillTo,
                oh.ord_company as OrderBy, --- oh.ord_customer as OrderBy, ---> PTS# 66418
                oh.ord_refnum as RefNum,     
                la.lgh_type1 as LghType1, 
                la.lgh_type2 as LghType2, 
                la.mpp_teamleader as TeamLeader, 
                oh.ord_status as OrderStatus, 
                la.mov_number as mov_number, legheader.lgh_etaalert1 as EtaStatus, legheader.lgh_etacomment as EtaComment,
                oh.ord_priority as 'Priority', 
                oh.ord_shipper as ord_shipper,
                oh.ord_consignee as ord_consignee,
                la.cmp_id_start as cmp_id_start,
                la.lgh_startcity as lgh_startcity,
                la.cmp_id_end as cmp_id_end,
                la.lgh_endcity as lgh_endcity,
                la.lgh_comment as lgh_comment,
                la.lgh_trc_comment as lgh_trc_comment,
                oh.ord_remark as Remarks,
                (select IsNull (mpp_gps_date, '') from manpowerprofile where manpowerprofile.mpp_id = oh.ord_driver1) as GPSDate,
                (select IsNull (mpp_gps_desc, '') from manpowerprofile where manpowerprofile.mpp_id = oh.ord_driver1) as GPSLocation,
                (select CAST(SUM(PD.pyd_amount)As Decimal (10,2))  from Paydetail PD Inner join Legheader L on( L.lgh_number = PD.lgh_number) 
                and (L.lgh_carrier = PD.asgn_id) and (PD.ord_hdrnumber = L.ord_hdrnumber) and l.ord_hdrnumber<>0 and l.ord_hdrnumber is not NULL and PD.asgn_type = 'CAR' Group by PD.pyd_amount) as 'Pay_Total'
              from legheader_active la join legheader on legheader.lgh_number = la.lgh_number    
                   inner join OrderHeaderRowRestrictedView oh on (la.ord_hdrnumber = oh.ord_hdrnumber)
               WHERE la.lgh_outstatus <> 'CMP'

            union 

            select rtrim(oh.ord_number)+ case when isnull(legheader.lgh_split_flag,'N') = 'N' then '' else '-' + legheader.lgh_split_flag end as OrderNumber, 
                la.lgh_outstatus as DispStatus, oh.ord_hdrnumber As OrderHeaderNumber,   
                la.lgh_startdate as StartDate, 
                la.lgh_enddate as EndDate, 
                la.lgh_startcty_nmstct as Leg_Start,
                la.lgh_endcty_nmstct as Leg_End,
                la.lgh_startregion1 as Leg_StartRegion1, la.lgh_startregion2 as Leg_StartRegion2, la.lgh_startregion3 as Leg_StartRegion3, la.lgh_startregion4 as Leg_StartRegion4,
                la.lgh_endregion1 as Leg_EndRegion1, la.lgh_endregion2 as Leg_EndRegion2, la.lgh_endregion3 as Leg_EndRegion3, la.lgh_endregion4 as Leg_EndRegion4,  
                la.ord_totalweight as Weight, FORMAT (oh.ord_totalcharge,'C','en-us') as Revenue,     
                la.ord_stopcount StopCount, la.lgh_driver1 as Driver1, la.evt_driver1_name Driver1Name, la.lgh_tractor as Tractor, la.lgh_primary_trailer as Trailer1,     
                la.lgh_carrier as Carrier, la.lgh_driver2 as Driver2, la.evt_driver2_name Driver2Name, la.lgh_primary_pup as Trailer2, oh.trl_type1 TrailerType,     
                la.cmd_code as CmdCode, la.fgt_description as CmdDescription, la.cmd_count as CmdCount,    
                la.lgh_class1 as RevType1, la.lgh_class1_name as RevType1Name, la.lgh_class2 as RevType2, la.lgh_class2_name as RevType2Name, la.lgh_class3 as RevType3, la.lgh_class3_name as RevType3Name, la.lgh_class4 as RevType4, la.lgh_class4_name as RevType4Name,
                ord_booked_revtype1 as BookingTerminal, la.lgh_booked_revtype1 as ExecutingTerminal, la.lgh_route RouteId,     
                la.lgh_number, la.lgh_tm_status as TotalMailStatus, la.lgh_tm_statusname as TotalMailStatusName, la.lgh_instatus as InStatus,     
                oh.ord_bookedby as BookedBy, oh.ord_billto as BillTo,
                oh.ord_company as OrderBy, --- oh.ord_customer as OrderBy, ---> PTS# 66418
                oh.ord_refnum as RefNum,     
                la.lgh_type1 as LghType1, 
                la.lgh_type2 as LghType2, 
                la.mpp_teamleader as TeamLeader, 
                oh.ord_status as OrderStatus, 
                la.mov_number as mov_number, legheader.lgh_etaalert1 as EtaStatus,  legheader.lgh_etacomment as EtaComment,
                oh.ord_priority as 'Priority', 
                oh.ord_shipper as ord_shipper,
                oh.ord_consignee as ord_consignee,
                la.cmp_id_start as cmp_id_start,
                la.lgh_startcity as lgh_startcity,
                la.cmp_id_end as cmp_id_end,
                la.lgh_endcity as lgh_endcity,
                la.lgh_comment as lgh_comment,
                la.lgh_trc_comment as lgh_trc_comment,
                oh.ord_remark as Remarks,
                (select IsNull (mpp_gps_date, '') from manpowerprofile where manpowerprofile.mpp_id = oh.ord_driver1) as GPSDate,
                (select IsNull (mpp_gps_desc, '') from manpowerprofile where manpowerprofile.mpp_id = oh.ord_driver1) as GPSLocation,
                (select CAST(SUM(PD.pyd_amount)As Decimal (10,2))  from Paydetail PD inner join Legheader L on( L.lgh_number = PD.lgh_number) 
                and (L.lgh_carrier = PD.asgn_id) and (PD.ord_hdrnumber = L.ord_hdrnumber)and l.ord_hdrnumber<>0 and l.ord_hdrnumber is not NULL and PD.asgn_type ='CAR' Group by PD.pyd_amount) as 'Pay_Total'
                from legheader_active la join legheader on (legheader.lgh_number = la.lgh_number)
                   left outer join orderheader oh on (la.ord_hdrnumber = oh.ord_hdrnumber)     
               WHERE    la.lgh_outstatus <> 'CMP' 
                        AND isnull(la.ord_hdrnumber, 0) = 0

        ) a
       left outer join company pc on (a.ord_shipper = pc.cmp_id)    
       left outer join company cc on (a.ord_consignee = cc.cmp_id)  
       join company fc on (a.cmp_id_start = fc.cmp_id)    
       join city fcy on (a.lgh_startcity = fcy.cty_code)    
       join company lc on (a.cmp_id_end = lc.cmp_id)    
       join city lcy on (a.lgh_endcity = lcy.cty_code)




GO
GRANT SELECT ON OperationsTripViewDetails_Venture_NOPAY TO PUBLIC
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the `dbo.GetMinutesAway(a.mov_number))` -Query into a single Select, so it takes any value.

I understand your Question as you would like to group the summery by any row. So a possible solution could be:

```
select a.OrderNumber, 
    a.DispStatus, a.OrderHeaderNumber, a.ord_shipper, a.ord_consignee,  
    a.StartDate, ISNULL(fc.cmp_id, '') as OriginId, ISNULL(fc.cmp_name, '') as OriginName, fcy.cty_nmstct as OriginCity, fcy.cty_state as OriginState, fcy.cty_zip as OriginZip,     
    a.EndDate, ISNULL(lc.cmp_id, '') as FinalId, ISNULL(lc.cmp_name, '') as FinalName, lcy.cty_nmstct as FinalCity, lcy.cty_state as FinalState, lcy.cty_zip As FinalZip,   
    (select sum(stp_lgh_mileage) from stops (nolock) where stops.lgh_number = a.lgh_number) as Mileage, a.Weight, a.Revenue,     
    a.StopCount, a.Driver1, a.Driver1Name, a.Tractor, a.Trailer1,     
    a.Carrier, a.Driver2, a.Driver2Name, a.Trailer2, a.TrailerType,     
    a.CmdCode, a.CmdDescription, a.CmdCount,    
    a.RevType1, a.RevType1Name, a.RevType2, a.RevType2Name, a.RevType3, a.RevType3Name, a.RevType4, a.RevType4Name,
    a.BookingTerminal, a.ExecutingTerminal, a.RouteId,     
    a.lgh_number, a.TotalMailStatus, a.TotalMailStatusName, a.InStatus,     
    a.BookedBy, a.BillTo, a.OrderBy, a.RefNum,     
    pc.cmp_id as PickupId, pc.cmp_name as PickupName, pc.cty_nmstct as PickupCity, pc.cmp_state as PickupState, pc.cmp_zip as PickupZip, pc.cmp_region1 as PickupRegion1, 
    pc.cmp_region2 as PickupRegion2, pc.cmp_region3 as PickupRegion3, pc.cmp_region4 as PickupRegion4,
    a.Leg_Start, a.Leg_End, a.Leg_StartRegion1, a.Leg_StartRegion2, a.Leg_StartRegion3, a.Leg_StartRegion4,
    a.Leg_EndRegion1,  a.Leg_EndRegion2, a.Leg_EndRegion3, a.Leg_EndRegion4, 
    cc.cmp_id as ConsigneeId, cc.cmp_name as ConsigneeName, cc.cty_nmstct as ConsigneeCity, cc.cmp_zip as ConsigneeZip, cc.cmp_state as ConsigneeState, cc.cmp_region1 as ConsigneeRegion1, 
    cc.cmp_region2 as ConsigneeRegion2, cc.cmp_region3 as ConsigneeRegion3, cc.cmp_region4 as ConsigneeRegion4,

    a.LghType1, 
    (select top 1 [name] from labelfile (nolock) where labeldefinition = 'LghType1' and abbr = a.LghType1) as LghType1Name, 
    a.LghType2, (select top 1 [name] from labelfile (nolock) where labeldefinition = 'LghType2' and abbr = a.lghtype2) as LghType2Name,
    a.TeamLeader, (select top 1 [name] from labelfile(nolock) where labeldefinition = 'TeamLeader' and abbr = a.TeamLeader) As TeamLeaderName,     
    a.OrderStatus, (select top 1 [name] from labelfile (nolock) where labeldefinition = 'DispStatus' and abbr = a.OrderStatus) as OrderStatusName, 
    a.mov_number, a.EtaStatus, a.EtaComment, a.[Priority],
     a.lgh_comment,
     a.lgh_trc_comment,
     a.Remarks,
     a.GPSDate,
     a.GPSLocation,
     a.Pay_Total,
    dbo.GetMinutesAway(a.mov_number) As MinutesAway
```

From...

...

```
Group by a.OrderNumber, 
        a.DispStatus, a.OrderHeaderNumber, a.ord_shipper, a.ord_consignee,  
        a.StartDate, ISNULL(fc.cmp_id, '') as OriginId, ISNULL(fc.cmp_name, '') as OriginName, fcy.cty_nmstct as OriginCity, fcy.cty_state as OriginState, fcy.cty_zip as OriginZip,     
        a.EndDate, ISNULL(lc.cmp_id, '') as FinalId, ISNULL(lc.cmp_name, '') as FinalName, lcy.cty_nmstct as FinalCity, lcy.cty_state as FinalState, lcy.cty_zip As FinalZip,   
        (select sum(stp_lgh_mileage) from stops (nolock) where stops.lgh_number = a.lgh_number) as Mileage, a.Weight, a.Revenue,     
        a.StopCount, a.Driver1, a.Driver1Name, a.Tractor, a.Trailer1,     
        a.Carrier, a.Driver2, a.Driver2Name, a.Trailer2, a.TrailerType,     
        a.CmdCode, a.CmdDescription, a.CmdCount,    
        a.RevType1, a.RevType1Name, a.RevType2, a.RevType2Name, a.RevType3, a.RevType3Name, a.RevType4, a.RevType4Name,
        a.BookingTerminal, a.ExecutingTerminal, a.RouteId,     
        a.lgh_number, a.TotalMailStatus, a.TotalMailStatusName, a.InStatus,     
        a.BookedBy, a.BillTo, a.OrderBy, a.RefNum,     
        pc.cmp_id as PickupId, pc.cmp_name as PickupName, pc.cty_nmstct as PickupCity, pc.cmp_state as PickupState, pc.cmp_zip as PickupZip, pc.cmp_region1 as PickupRegion1, 
        pc.cmp_region2 as PickupRegion2, pc.cmp_region3 as PickupRegion3, pc.cmp_region4 as PickupRegion4,
        a.Leg_Start, a.Leg_End, a.Leg_StartRegion1, a.Leg_StartRegion2, a.Leg_StartRegion3, a.Leg_StartRegion4,
        a.Leg_EndRegion1,  a.Leg_EndRegion2, a.Leg_EndRegion3, a.Leg_EndRegion4, 
        cc.cmp_id as ConsigneeId, cc.cmp_name as ConsigneeName, cc.cty_nmstct as ConsigneeCity, cc.cmp_zip as ConsigneeZip, cc.cmp_state as ConsigneeState, cc.cmp_region1 as ConsigneeRegion1, 
        cc.cmp_region2 as ConsigneeRegion2, cc.cmp_region3 as ConsigneeRegion3, cc.cmp_region4 as ConsigneeRegion4,

        a.LghType1, 
        (select top 1 [name] from labelfile (nolock) where labeldefinition = 'LghType1' and abbr = a.LghType1) as LghType1Name, 
        a.LghType2, (select top 1 [name] from labelfile (nolock) where labeldefinition = 'LghType2' and abbr = a.lghtype2) as LghType2Name,
        a.TeamLeader, (select top 1 [name] from labelfile(nolock) where labeldefinition = 'TeamLeader' and abbr = a.TeamLeader) As TeamLeaderName,     
        a.OrderStatus, (select top 1 [name] from labelfile (nolock) where labeldefinition = 'DispStatus' and abbr = a.OrderStatus) as OrderStatusName, 
        a.mov_number, a.EtaStatus, a.EtaComment, a.[Priority],
         a.lgh_comment,
         a.lgh_trc_comment,
         a.Remarks,
         a.GPSDate,
         a.GPSLocation,
         a.Pay_Total
```

Comment: The minutes away was working though. I was only trying to add a total pay per leg column to an already functioning SQL view. I can't rewrite the whole thing. Any help on just the Carrier pay column?

Comment: Another problem, is this is not just From a single table, this has a lot of joins from other tables making this work. all the joins are missing from your rewrite.